# Characters to Bytes

Tags: character, byte

What's a good estimate/conversion/formula to figure out X# characters = Y# bytes?

Comment: It depends entirely on the character encoding scheme you use. Which one are you using?

Comment: The default encoding in MySQL is Latin-1, so if you've not changed it that's 1 byte per character, but you can only store a very restricted set of characters. Consider using UTF-8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It entirely depends on the encoding and potentially the data.

For UTF-16, if you know that all the characters are in the Basic Multilingual Plane, the answer will be bytes = 2 * characters.

For UTF-8, if everything is in the ASCII range, then bytes = characters - but if there are lots of Far Eastern characters, it could be as much as bytes = 3 * characters (and that's still assuming the Basic Multilingual Plane).

Other encodings obviously have different scenarios. Could you give more details about your situation (and your platform)? Do you want an accurate calculated value based on actual characters? Do you know anything about the text you're going to encode?

Comment: UTF-8 can use up to 4 bytes for a single character.

Comment: @Christoffer: Even within the BMP? Not according to http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8

Answer (score 0):

For ANSI, I would think 1 byte to char but for unicode I would think 2 bytes per char. Although there are probably multi byte patterns too.